# Is there a tool/method that can help me package the nodejs backend code so that I no longer need to download node_modules?

Tags: node.js, webpack, rollup, vite

I have a express project,when deploying,I should download or copy the node_modules to my server.
is there a good tool/method like vite or webpack could help me to pack my code?

Answer (score 1):

Try `pkg` [github](https://github.com/vercel/pkg). you can package nodejs and create executable for `linux`, `win`, `mac`.